# mangento 2 Cron Job is not scheduled with fix time

Tags: magento2, cron, crontab, magento-cron

I want to execute cron every day at 10.05 so i have define crontab.xml as below

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Cron:etc/crontab.xsd">
    <group id="default">
       <job name="test_cron" instance="Vendor\Module\Cron\Test" method="execute">
            <schedule>5 10 * * *</schedule>
        </job>
    </group>
</config>
```

and this "test_cron" not iserted in "cron_schedule" table.

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are specifying the exact hours or minutes, magento calculates them with the timezone you defined inside Store -> Configuration -> General -> Locale Option -> Timezone (Default Config) to make entry in cron_schedule table.

Do not consider it to be your systems's current time.

Answer (score 0):

is that cron running on the server?

try with * * * * * and check is that entry doing everry min

Comment: i have check with ' * * * * * ' and its working . but i want to execute cron every day @ 10.05

Comment: are you using any module related to cron? have you run cron using n98?

Comment: i have already run a command "php bin/magento cron:install" . i don't use any module related to cron